# Вывод категории картинкой в OC 2.0.3.1

Tags: php, opencart

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести категории в формате картинка категории + название в OpenCart 2.0.3.1 ?
Что нужно в контролерах переносить?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нашел подходящий бесплатный модуль - [Category Wall для OC 2](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=21103&filter_search=category%20wall)